# Duplicate casting

Tags: java, casting, corba

My colleague asks me a question which I can't find the final answer myself, the question is about object casting.

Say I have a class A, and a Factory class, In the factory class, I want to create the A instance:

```
Public class Factory {

    public A createA1() {
       Object instance = get_A_Object();
       //Single casting
       return (A) instance;
    }

     public A createA2() {
       Object instance = get_A_Object();
       // Duplicate casting or more
       return (A) (A) instance;
    }
}
```

My question is:

What's the different between single casting in method createA1() vs duplicate casting in method createA2()? Do they always get the same result?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, my colleague asks me about this line of code:

```
org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB orb = ((org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init((String[])localObject2, localProperties)); 
return (org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)(org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)(org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)(org.omg.CO‌​RBA_2_5.ORB)(orb);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That duplicate is completely redundant. You only have to cast once.

Here's an exercise. If you load this in your IDE, and remove the casts one-by-one, at what point does it start complaining about your types ?

In fact, in your amended question, you don't have to cast at all!

```
org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB orb = ((org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init((String[])localObject2, localProperties));
```

You've declared `orb`'s type in the assignment.

Comment: I confused 'cause my colleague ask about this code: 

org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB orb = ((org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init((String[])localObject2, localProperties));
   return (org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)(org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)(org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)(org.omg.CORBA_2_5.ORB)(orb);  

Do you have any comment on this?

Comment: I agree, at the first sight, it seems to be superfluous, but that's it or there's others behind the scene?

Comment: It seems that the casting is duplicated. Tks

Answer (score 2):

No difference.

```
int i = (int)(int)1
```

Evaluates to (int)1 to 1.

Completely redundant.

**EDIT:**
Irrelevant to the question but.. you shouldn't need to cast. Your Factory should at least return  an inteface. Looks like code smell.

Answer (score 1):

Esentially you are performing a cast on the cast.

```
Object obj = (Object)(Integer)thing.getObeject()
```

Essentially you could recast after casting - fairly pointless if you ask me..

Or even more rediclous stuff like:

```
Integer integer1 = (Integer)(Object)thing.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Functionally it looks the same so I would say the double casting is redundant.

It might be something deep down in the byte code but the compiler is pretty efficient so I wouldnt think there would be anything. The test below shows that functionally they are the same

```
@Test
public void testCasting {

    Object obj = new String("abc");

    String s1 = (String) obj;
    String s2 = (String)(String)  obj;

    assertEquals("abc", s1);
    assertEquals("abc", s2);
    assertEquals(s1, s2);
}
```

This test passes

Answer (score 1):

its redundant

```
        Number num = (Number)(Number) (new Integer(10));
```

casting an integer to Number twice. there would be no difference

Comment: yep just creating more over head - how about Integer int1 = (Integer)(Number)(Integer) (new Integer(10));  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just think in this way,

You have casted one object say

> (A)obj

now the obj became A class type, the we doesn't required to cast again, even if we do there will no harm it will waste the process.

Answer (score 1):

From the Java Language Specification standpoint, this is how it looks:

`instance` – an expression of type `Object`

`(A) instance` – an expression of type `A`

`(A) (A) instance` – casting an expression of type `A` to type `A`.

Another way to articulate it is to compare with this code:

```
final Object instance = get_A_Object();
final A a = (A) instance;
final A a0 = (A) a;
```